Proceedure to kill session in Oracle
I have created a procedure to capture long running session and want to kill those session from procedure itself.
Procedure is capturing the sessions but kill session alter command is not working from the procedure.
Getting below error.

00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

Please guide me how to resolve this error.
What grants needs be provided.

This is a DBA task. Even with alter system privs, you have to be careful not to kill things you shouldn't.

Procedure should be created with authid definer and then execution privliege granted to regular user. This way you don't have to grant alter system privilege to regular users.

alter system cancel sql might be slightly less dangerous, but it still requires alter system privilege. The procedure probably belongs in a separate schema.


but kill session alter command is not working from the procedure.

Two options I can think of:

user - which runs that procedure - isn't granted required privileges (alter system)
it is granted, via role. That won't work in named stored procedures, which means that you'll have to grant that privilege directly to user who is supposed to do that (kill someone's session, that is).

